# Default targets when adding new class in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

When I'm trying to add new class in Xcode, I always get same window in last step, that suggest adding my class to 'test' target. But most of the time I need to add file to regular app target. How can I change this behaviour ?

[image: Xcode add new class last step - specify class name and targets]

Comment: I have the same problem and I haven't found a solution :(

Comment: Xcode suggests to add a new class to the active target. What target is active in your project when you are adding it?

Comment: Xcode 4.2 at least seems to remember the last setting.